# rviz2 only render boxes

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Been a long time i worked with ROS, so for my new project i installed ROS2 Foxy (clean ubuntu setup)
Starting with my URDF and RVIZ2, it seems im only able to render boxes in rviz.

Also tried loading my old robot model, tried examples, cylinders and spheres are not visible.

Is this a known issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374069/rviz2-only-render-boxes/) by [RandyD](https://answers.ros.org/users/29157/randyd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2021-03-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
the same happened to me, solved with LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8";
However this is still a bug as boxes work properly.

---

Originally posted by [Tereza](https://answers.ros.org/users/73215/tereza/) with karma: 26 on 2021-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Katritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/76210/katritz/) on 2021-06-17**:
Hey, where did you put the command LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8";?
I have the same problem with the urdf tutorial for ROS2 Foxy. Boxes are visible in rviz2 but nothing else.

**Comment by [Tereza](https://answers.ros.org/users/73215/tereza/) on 2021-06-18**:
I run ros2 launch from terminal, so I put it before the run command:

```
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"; ros2 launch <package> <launch_file>
```

This will set LC_NUMERIC for subshell where ros2 launch runs.

**Comment by [Katritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/76210/katritz/) on 2021-06-18**:
Super, this works! Thanks!